# Drupal - hiding advanced post settings from users

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-permissions

I'm getting lost in the sea of allowable permissions in Drupal.

I have a content-type which has revision and workflow settings all nicely setup, but I do not want my users to be able to see these options (new revision each time automatically, etc).

From what I understand, this information goes away when you disable the 'administer node' field, however when I disable this my link for editing nodes disappears for these users.

My question is twofold then:

1. What is the proper way to hide this access from users
2. If disabling 'administer nodes' is the key, then how do I direct my
   users to have access to edit their content-type once it is created? 
   (currently it points to `admin/content/node`)

I have seen solutions that involve overriding the template.php file, but I'd rather not do this.

**Edit**

Here is a clarification of the behavior:

*Current permissions*

```
                                 special role
administer nodes                     [x]
create <custom> content              [x]
delete any <custom>content           [x]
delete own <custom>content           [x]
edit any <custom> content            [x]
```

So, with this snippet of settings, my users can see things like 'revision information,' 'publishing options,' etc.

I want these advanced features to NOT appear for them.  What I have learned is that this can be controlled by disabling 'administer nodes.'

The problem is that when this is unchecked, my users lose the option in their menu which points to editing my content.  Currently, this points to `admin/content/node`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question as the solution I'm going to recommend is very straighforward: In the permissions page there is a permission, edit *any* story content, edit *any* page content... for all the users you want, you can assign them a role and mark the checkbox here. This will allow them to still edit the nodes and yet will avoid all the extra junk that you see in the node edit form that you get if you have the administer nodes permission checked.

**Edit:** As pointed out in my comment below (and by googletorp), to get something like `admin/content/node` you'll have to build it using VBO (Views Bulk Operations) (after disabling administer nodes)

Comment: @NoParrots: Please see my edit...I thought that I had that functionality set, but my menu link for editing a page disappears from my user's menu once I disable 'administer nodes'

Comment: First, make sure that user is member of that special role. When you create a user you need to assign all applicable roles to that user. Secondly, when page edit disappears thats because "edit any page content" should also be marked as selected on the permissions page. Please deselect administer nodes permission of course. That is not required.

Comment: Of course you'll need to create a special content listing using VBO. You need VBO cause otherwise special role will not be able to see the whole list at admin/content/node

Comment: @NoParrots: User is in the special role.  Administer nodes deselected.  Edit any page content selected (also Edit any <content> selected).  Menu item still disappears.  I don't understand, because for this role create/edit/delete any <content> is checked...is my link to administrate incorrect perhaps?

Comment: When you say menu item still disappears you mean `admin/content/node` disappears? That is expected. Now you will need to make your own sort of admin using VBO (Views Bulk Operations) as suggested by googletorp also. See some tutorials about it. Very easy to make a VBO that is as good, if not better than what you used to see on `admin/content/node`

Comment: Ahh...I think I *finally* understand....using VBO will get me the functionality of the current `admin/content/node` listing, but allow me to restrict it to my special content-type and provide a link that way

Comment: Yes correct. Using VBO you can build a control panel that can restrict itself only to the content types that you want the users with Special Role to control. If all you want is a simple edit link then all you need to do is build a simple view and add the two fields: Node: Title and Node: Edit Link

Comment: @NoParrots: all i really needed was the listing of nodes within that content-type...a simple view with edit / delete links was all i needed...thanks once again!

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own version of `admin/content/node` and tweak it, to fx only show nodes created by the user.

Doing this is quite easy with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and [Views bulk operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). I believe VBO comes with a prebuilt view that does this already, that you can tweak into your liking.

Comment: so VBO will give me greater formatting control over what type of info is shown through my forms?  the issue is less the 'nodes created by user' and more showing the advanced node options that, by default, seem to be enabled....

Comment: @espais: You don't alter forms, but instead create new. VBO allow you to do bulk operations, like changing status of several nodes at once and that sort of thing. If you only want to display the nodes, you wont need VBO.